# Is it possible to speed up this pandas data extraction?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
X = []
Y = []
for i in cell_Data['ID']:
    A = face_Data.query(f"Cell_0 == {i} or Cell_1 == {i}")
    X.append(np.average(A['X']))
    Y.append(np.average(A['Y']))

cell_Data['X'] = X
cell_Data['Y'] = Y
print("Cell Coordinates Obtained")
```

face_Data is a dataframe containing two columns Cell_0 and Cell_1, both are IDs of cells that bound each face. face_Data also has its own coordinates in X and Y columns. My goal is to calculate coordinates of cell from that. Since the query value itself is changing everytime, I can't vectorize them directly.

cell_Data['ID'] = list(1,2,....N)

I could get the cell coordinates but looping through each record takes huge time as the size of face_Data is typically of order of 5 or 6.

Sample Data looks like this.

```py
face_data = pd.DataFrame({
             'ID' = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
             'X': [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.2],
             'Y': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
             'Cell_0' = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7],
             'Cell_1'] = [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
            })
cell_data = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ...], columns = ['ID'])
```

How the data grid looks like is shown below:

```
(5) | (6) | (7) | (8) 
    4-----5-----6-----
(1) | (2) | (3) | (4)
    1-----2-----3-----
```

The (cell_ID) is shown in brackets, the face_ID is shown below the vertical line. Just a 2D cartesian grid.

face_Data.head looks like this:
[image]

Comment: please provide a **reproducible** example of `face_Data` and `cell_Data`

Comment: I have added sample structure of dataframe. But the actual data is too huge to add here. Typically what it does is try to check which are the boundary faces of each cell (by comparing its ID in Cell_0 or Cell_1 columns) and from their coordinates, find the cell coordinates (just averaging), assuming a cartesian grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) we can archive this:

```py
face_Data = pd.DataFrame({
             'X': [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.2],
             'Y': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
             'Cell_0': [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2],
             'Cell_1': [2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2]
            })

face_Data["face_id"] = face_Data.index + 1
cell_Data = face_Data.melt(id_vars=["X", "Y", "face_id"], value_name="ID")\
   .drop(columns=["variable"])\
   .groupby(["face_id", "ID"])\
   .first()\
   .groupby("ID")\
   .mean()
```

The idea is to create a table that has only one column for the ID, this is done with `melt`:

```py
>>> face_Data["face_id"] = face_Data.index + 1
>>> face_Data.melt(id_vars=["X", "Y", "face_id"], value_name="ID")
      X  Y variable  ID
      X  Y  face_id variable  ID
0   0.0  1        1   Cell_0   1
1   0.1  1        2   Cell_0   2
2   0.2  1        3   Cell_0   1
3   0.0  2        4   Cell_0   3
4   0.1  2        5   Cell_0   1
5   0.2  2        6   Cell_0   2
6   0.0  1        1   Cell_1   2
7   0.1  1        2   Cell_1   3
8   0.2  1        3   Cell_1   3
9   0.0  2        4   Cell_1   1
10  0.1  2        5   Cell_1   4
11  0.2  2        6   Cell_1   2
```

But if we would do a group by ID (`.drop(columns=["variable"]).groupby("ID").average()`) we would count the row with face_id 6 two times (row 11 and 5 in the output above).
This happens for rows in `face_Data` where Cell_0 == Cell_1.
To remove these rows we do a group by `face_id` and `ID` followed by a `first()`:

```
>>> face_Data.melt(id_vars=["X", "Y", "face_id"], value_name="ID")\
...    .drop(columns=["variable"])\
...    .groupby(["face_id", "ID"])\
...    .first()
              X  Y
face_id ID        
1       1   0.0  1
        2   0.0  1
2       2   0.1  1
        3   0.1  1
3       1   0.2  1
        3   0.2  1
4       1   0.0  2
        3   0.0  2
5       1   0.1  2
        4   0.1  2
6       2   0.2  2
```

Note that the point (X=0.2  Y=2) only appears once.

On this table we can now do a `groupby("ID).average()` to average all the X and Y values for the same ID:

```
>>> face_Data.melt(id_vars=["X", "Y", "face_id"], value_name="ID")\
...    .drop(columns=["variable"])\
...    .groupby(["face_id", "ID"])\
...    .first()\
...    .groupby("ID")\
...    .mean()
        X         Y
ID                 
1   0.075  1.500000
2   0.100  1.333333
3   0.100  1.333333
4   0.100  2.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate response. I will try to implement it and see if it matches with the larger dataset that I have and revert it back. Only thing I want to point out here is, Cell_0 and Cell_1 are two neighboring cells connected by a common face. No data pair will have same ID in Cell_0 and Cell_1 as you have taken to be 2 for both for face_ID 6.

Comment: If you do not have rows where Cell_0 is equal to Cell_1 you can use this shorter version:`
cell_Data = face_Data.melt(id_vars=["X", "Y"], value_name="ID").drop(columns=["variable"]).groupby("ID").mean()`

Comment: I ran it. Two problems it is showing. One, there are many cells without any coordinates (empty values). Also, the resulting datasize is twice the size expected for cell_Data. I will correct the question and add some schematics of what I am trying to achieve. But This has given me some good start. I will try to look more into melt() Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Runinho for the answer.

This worked for me.

```py
face_Data['face_id'] = face_Data.index + 1
test = face_Data.melt(id_vars=["face_id", "X", "Y"], value_vars = ['Cell_0', 'Cell_1'], value_name = 'ID')
test = test.drop(columns = ['variable']).groupby('ID').mean()[1:]
cell_Data['X'] = test['X']
cell_Data['Y'] = test['Y']
```